# persian to gregorian date convert

Tags: android, calendar

I have successfully converted my current Gregorian date to Persian (Jalali).
However, I need to convert it back to the Gregorian calendar date.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
 SimpleDateFormat sdf_timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.US);
 date1 = sdf4.parse(input_date);
 time = sdf_timeformat.parse(input_time);


 Locale locale = new Locale("en_us@calendar=gregorian");
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
 DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, locale);
 String date = df.format(date1);
```

Comment: Maybe edit your question: What is "geogorian" calendar? Gregorian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this perfect library for converting Jalali and Gregorian date:
https://github.com/razeghi71/JalaliCalendar

To Create a Jalali Date with specified year, month, day use the constructor :

```
JalaliCalendar jalaliCalendar = new JalaliCalendar(1395, 1, 28);
```

To Covert a Gregorian Date to Jalali :

```
JalaliCalendar jalaliDate = new JalaliCalendar(new GregorianCalendar(2016, 4, 16));
```

To Convert a Jalali Date to Gregorian Date :

```
JalaliCalendar jalaliCalendar = new JalaliCalendar(1395, 1, 28);
GregorianCalendar gc = jalaliCalendar.toGregorian();
```

Comment: are jalali and persian calender same ?

Comment: Yes, they are. 
Jalali, Persian and Shamsi calenders are same.